# The metric tensor at $p$ satisfies $g_{a b, c d} + g_{a d,b c} + g_{a c, d b} = 0$ in a normal coordinate system centered at $p$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have found this identity in a paper that I am reading:

> On a Riemannian $n$-manifold $(M,g)$,  consider a **normal** coordinate system $\{x^i\}_{i=1,\dots,n}$centered at $p\in M$. Then 
>   $$g_{a b, c d}(p) + g_{a d,b c}(p) + g_{a c, d b}(p) = 0$$ 
>   Where  $g_{a b, c d}  = \frac{\partial^2 g(\frac \partial {\partial x^a }, \frac \partial {\partial x^b })} {\partial {x^d}\partial {x^c}}. $
>   How can I prove this statement?

I recall that in a normal coordinate system centered at $p$ the following identities hold (notice that are true only at $p$):
$$ g_{i j}(p) = \delta_{i j}  \text{  (Kronecker delta)}$$ 
$$ \partial_{x^k} g_{i j}(p) = 0 $$
$$ \Gamma_{i j}^k (p) = 0$$
$$\partial_{x^k}\Gamma_{i j}^l(p) = \frac 1 2 (g_{i l,j k}(p) + g_{j l,i k}(p)- g_{i j, l k}(p))$$
Where $\Gamma_{i,j}^k$ are the Christoffel symbols of the Levi-Civita connection induced by $g$.

So we have that  (at the point $p$)
$$g_{a b,c d} + g_{a d, b c} + g_{a c,d b} = 2 \partial_{x^d} \Gamma_{b c}^a + g_{b c, a d} + g_{a c,d b} =  2 \partial_{x^d} \Gamma_{b c}^a+ 2 \partial_{x^d} \Gamma_{b a}^c + g_{a b, c d} $$

The fourth equation seems to be promising  but still I don't see how to conclude.

Comment: Do you know the expression for the Riemann curvature $R_p$ in normal coordinates?

Comment: Do you mean 
$R_{ k l i j } = \frac 1 2 (g_{j k , l i} - g_{jlki}+  g_{i l, k j} - g_{i k, l j}) $ ?

Comment: It seems that it follows from this [taylor expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884794/the-taylor-expansion-of-the-metric-at-the-origin-in-geodesic-coordinates) and Bianchi identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gauss Lemma can be stated as 
$$\sum_i x^iu^i = \sum _ix^ig_{i j}(x) u^j \quad \forall u \in \mathbb{R}^n$$
in *normal* coordinates $\{x^i\}_{i=1,\dots, n}$. In particular we have that $$1)\quad \quad x^j = x^ig_{ij}(x).$$
Deriving 1) along $\partial_k$ we obtain 
$$\partial_k x^j = \delta_k^j = \partial_k x^i g_{i j}(x) + x^i g_{i j,k}(x) = g_{k j}(x) + x^i g_{i j,k}(x)$$
Deriving again along $\partial_r$ we obtain
$$ 0 = g_{k j, r}(x) + g_{r j, k}(x) + x^i g_{i j,k r}(x) $$
Deriving again along $\partial_l$ we obtain
$$0 = g_{k j, r l}(x) + g_{r j, k l}(x) +  g_{l j,k r}(x)  + x^i g_{l j,k r l}(x)$$
Now we evaluate at the origin this last equation to get
$$0 = g_{k j, r l}(O) + g_{r j, k l}(O) +  g_{l j,k r}(O)  = g_{j k, r l}(O) + g_{j r, l k}(O) +  g_{ j l,k r}(O) $$
which is the wanted equation.